# Writing a class under another class using function

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am writing Python code using classes and tkinter, and I want to open another window when I click a button in the main window. I want to design this new window different from the main and add some properties (function) to it which are not in the main window.

Let me show you my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Uygulama(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.araclar()

    def araclar(self):
        self.etiket1 = Label(text="WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM", fg="blue", font="Times 15 bold", 
           bg="grey")
        self.etiket1.pack()

        self.etiket2 = Label(text="Hello world", fg="black", font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
        self.etiket2.place(rely=0.95, relx=0.70)
     
        self.dugme5=Button(text="click here to open new window", command=self.bk4, 
               fg="black", 
            bg="blue", font="bold")
        self.dugme5.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.78)

    def bk4(self):
        class Uygulama2:
            def __init__(self):
                self.araclar2()
            def araclar2(self):
                self.dugme6=Button(text="click for pinting", 
                command=self.bk5, fg="black", 
                       bg="red",font="bold")
                self.dugme6.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5)

            def bk5(self):
                print("hello world")
        

        pencere2 = Tk()
        pencere2.title("This is a new windows")
        pencere2.geometry("390x350+860+30")
        pencere2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        pencere2.configure(bg="grey")
        uyg2 = Uygulama2()
        pencere2.mainloop()
    

pencere = Tk()
pencere.title("This is main window")
pencere.geometry("550x550+300+30")
pencere.resizable(width=False, height=False)
pencere.configure(bg="grey")
uyg = Uygulama()
mainloop()
```

**My problem:** When I click to the button in main windows, another window opened, but the button which must be on the second window appears on the main window. How can I move it to the second window?

Moreover, I am planning to add more functions and widgets to the second window, but I do not want them to appear or run in the main window which is `Pencere=Tk()`.

What's more, is it possible to add a third window which is written using classes and opened on the second window like this?

Comment: First avoid creating more than one instance of `Tk()`, use `Toplevel()` for windows other than the root window. Second avoid calling `mainloop()` more than once.  Third it is better to specify the parent of the widget when creating it, otherwise it is created as child of the root window, so `Button(text="click for pinting", ...)` will be created as child of the root window instead of the newly open window.

Comment: `Button(pencere2, text="click for pinting", ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a running version of your code:

```py
from tkinter import *


class Uygulama(Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        # Title of the main window
        self.title("This is main window")
        # Set the size and position of the window
        self.geometry("550x550+300+30")
        # Disable resizing of the window
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        # Set the background color of the window
        self.configure(bg="grey")

        # Create a label with text "WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM"
        self.etiket1 = Label(self, text="WELCOME TO MY PROGRAM", fg="blue", font="Times 15 bold",
                             bg="grey")
        # Pack the label
        self.etiket1.pack()

        # Create a label with text "Hello world"
        self.etiket2 = Label(self, text="Hello world", fg="black",
                             font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
        # Place the label on the window
        self.etiket2.place(rely=0.95, relx=0.70)

        # Create a button that opens a new window when clicked
        self.dugme5 = Button(self, text="click here to open new window", command=self.bk4,
                             fg="black",
                             bg="blue", font="bold")
        self.dugme5.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.78)

    # Function to create the new window
    def bk4(self):
        Uygulama2(self)


class Uygulama2(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        # Title of the new window
        self.title("This is a new window")
        # Set the size and position of the window
        self.geometry("390x350+860+30")
        # Disable resizing of the window
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        # Set the background color of the window
        self.configure(bg="grey")

        # Create a button that prints "hello world" when clicked
        self.dugme6 = Button(self, text="click for printing",
                             command=self.bk5, fg="black",
                             bg="red", font="bold")
        self.dugme6.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

        # Create a button that opens a new window when clicked
        self.dugme7 = Button(self, text="click here to open new window", command=self.bk6,
                             fg="black",
                             bg="blue", font="bold")
        self.dugme7.pack()

    # Function to print "hello world"
    def bk5(self):
        print("hello world")

    # Function to create the new window
    def bk6(self):
        Uygulama3(self)


class Uygulama3(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        # Title of the new window
        self.title("This is another new window")
        # Set the size and position of the window
        self.geometry("390x350+1260+30")
        # Disable resizing of the window
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        # Set the background color of the window
        self.configure(bg="grey")

        # Create a label with text "Test window 3"
        self.etiket3 = Label(self, text="Test window 3", fg="black",
                             font="Times 11 bold", bg="grey")
        # pack the label on the window
        self.etiket3.pack()


uyg = Uygulama()
uyg.mainloop()
```

I have added another button which opens another window when pressed to show you how you could implement that.

Comment: thanks for nice answer, i want to ask something else. Lets assume that we have some functions in the main class , and we want to use them in the subclass, what can we do ? I tried to add "Uygulama.__init__" in Uygulama2 class , but when i run the function which is taken from main class , then the main class reset itself and override somethings .For example "This is main window" appear two times in the main windows and the outputs in the main windows deleted..  Do you know any solution to use values and functions obtained from the main class in subclassess ?

Comment: I tried to add some functions in your answer code such as printing function in main class , and i wanted to use it in Uygulama2 such that when you click the button it runs the function in the main and print the result , but it gives error

Comment: It gives attribute error and say Uygulama2 does not have that function

Comment: @ulahh you can add this here for example to add another button in Uygulama3 that uses the print function from Uygulama2

`self.dugme8 = Button(self, text="test", command=master.bk5, fg="black", bg="blue", font="bold")`
`self.dugme8.pack()`

This calls its masters bk5 ans since in this case the master of Uygulama3  is Uygulama2 the Uygulama2.bk5() gets called